# Split large space separated file into chucks of small files

Tags: java, algorithm, distributed-computing

I have an input file of about 2 GB. It contains numbers (duplicates possible) from 1 to 9999 and are space separated. I want to read the file in small chunks (chunks of say 100000 or 20000). What approach should I take?

I am planning to process these chunks of data on different nodes in distributed fashion. I cannot use HDFS or any other file system that would chunk data automatically.

Answer (score 0):

When you store that 2GB of data in the HDFS, it will be broken down into blocks. The default block size for HDFS is 64MB. You can set it to any size that you wish. For example, if you set the size to be 100MB, your data will be broken down into approximately 20 blocks.

On the other hand, when you are processing the data through MapReduce, you can decide the amount of data that you want to process by defining the number of mappers to use. You do this by setting up the split size.

For example, if you have 20 blocks of size 100MB in your HDFS like mentioned earlier, if you do not set any split size, Hadoop will figure that out for you and assign 20 mappers. But if you specify, for example the split size to be 25MB, then you will have 80 mappers processing your data.

It is important to note, this is just an example. In practical, the higher number of mappers does not mean faster processing time. You'd have to look into optimisation in order to get the best number of splits to use.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not planning to store file in HDFS. I am looking for some approach to break the file in chunks through a program and then later use for processing.